# Convert datetime into time ago

Tags: php

I need to convert DateTime into the year, month, days, hours, minutes, seconds ago like as yahoo question asked 5week ago, or 1 year ago or 1 month ago, my date is saved in the database like this: `2011-11-30 05:25:50`.

Now I want to show like year, month, days, hours, minutes and seconds in PHP like: `how much year, how many months , days,  hours,  minutes,  seconds` ago, but need only one time unit show like it will be year or days or hours or minutes or seconds.

I have searched about this but not understand how I can do this, I know there are many questions at this topic on Stack Overflow, maybe it is duplicate but I am unable to solve my issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't convert a date into a period of time. You need **two** dates for that to work.

Comment: You want the difference between that time and now, I suppose? http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php

Comment: No I don't want difference

Comment: @ali Then how are you planning on turning "2011" into "2 years"?

Comment: it is only example: I just want this date time `2011-11-30 05:25:50` into correct formate

Comment: I have question table there is save asked_date 2011-11-30 05:25:50 now I want to show this question was asked 'year,month,days,hours,minutes,seconds ago

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you mean relative to the present (if you don't, please clarify your question), you could use this:

```
$then = new DateTime('2011-11-30 05:25:50');
$now = new DateTime();
$delta = $now->diff($then);

$quantities = array(
    'year' => $delta->y,
    'month' => $delta->m,
    'day' => $delta->d,
    'hour' => $delta->h,
    'minute' => $delta->i,
    'second' => $delta->s);

$str = '';
foreach($quantities as $unit => $value) {
    if($value == 0) continue;
    $str .= $value . ' ' . $unit;
    if($value != 1) {
        $str .= 's';
    }
    $str .=  ', ';
}
$str = $str == '' ? 'a moment ' : substr($str, 0, -2);

echo $str;
```

Output:

```
1 year, 9 months, 17 days, 14 hours, 31 minutes, 31 seconds
```

Comment: They clarified, they don't. [See this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18787790/difference-between-2-time-values/18787809#18787809) for a more concise way to do this.

Comment: I have question table there is save asked_date 2011-11-30 05:25:50 now I want to show this question was asked 'year,month,days,hours,minutes,seconds ago

Comment: Retrieve that timestamp from the database in the normal way, put `$result['asked_date']` into the constructor of the first `DateTime` (`$then`), and append ` ago` to the final `$str`.

Comment: Yes - passing no arguments initialises the DateTime object to the current timestamp.

Comment: Thank you what I was want,but now can you edit your answer please as if there is no year,no month and no days it shows 0 year,0 month so on,but I want to only that values that are exist mean if there are seconds then return me second , I mean if else condition :)

Comment: There's a much easier way - see my edit. `if($value == 0) continue;`

Comment: Saved my life. Thanks a lot George !!

Answer (score 1):

I've always used this function:

```
function when($datetime) {   

    define("SECOND", 1);
    define("MINUTE", 60 * SECOND);
    define("HOUR", 60 * MINUTE); define("DAY", 24 * HOUR);
    define("MONTH", 30 * DAY); $delta = time() - strtotime($datetime);

    // convert

    if($delta < 1 * MINUTE) { return $delta == 1 ? "one second ago" : $delta." seconds ago"; }
    if($delta < 2 * MINUTE) { return "a minute ago"; } if($delta < 45 * MINUTE) { return floor($delta / MINUTE)." minutes ago"; }
    if($delta < 90 * MINUTE) { return "an hour ago"; } if($delta < 24 * HOUR) { return floor($delta / HOUR)." hours ago"; }
    if($delta < 48 * HOUR) { return "yesterday"; } if($delta < 30 * DAY) { return floor($delta / DAY)." days ago"; }
    if($delta < 12 * MONTH) { $months = floor($delta / DAY / 30); return $months <= 1 ? "one month ago" : $months." months ago"; }
    else { $years = floor($delta / DAY / 365); return $years <= 1 ? "one year ago" : $years." years ago"; }

}
```

echo when(YOUR DATE HERE) will return the best format of relative time, which might be days, hours, or if it wasn't that long ago, even in seconds.

Comment: They don't want the difference between two dates

Comment: I'm with @Esaevian then, this question makes no sense.

Comment: Thank you: I used your method and it echo this error:
Constant SECOND already defined: i am using this function in yii model class

Comment: Could you make sure that the function is only being included once?

Comment: `class Question extends CActiveRecord
   {
   public static function when($datetime) {
    ........
     }

    }`

Comment: I have question table there is save asked_date 2011-11-30 05:25:50 now I want to show this question was asked 'year,month,days,hours,minutes,seconds ago

Comment: This function won't do that. This will only return either a months, days, hours, or seconds ago. Try including the script higher in the document and calling in when needed.

Comment: The value of a constant can be the value of another constant?

Answer (score 0):

Try this: 
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

PHP has a nice function `strtotime` all ready for your needs.

That'll give you a timestamp, then you can just do math from there from whatever date you are subtracting from.

Comment: But that's it, they're *not* doing math on two different dates

Comment: I made an assumption that they had a second date ready to go. Still, you can convert a single date to a string like that if you want something like `2011 years, 11 months, 30 days, 5 hours, 25 minutes, 50 seconds`

Comment: Hmph, nevermind, I just saw ali's comment. Now this question makes no sense.

Comment: I don't want difference.

Comment: @ali Then your question makes no sense. What it the logic of converting "2011" to "2 years" for instance?

Comment: I have question table there is save asked_date `2011-11-30 05:25:50` now I want to show this question was asked 'year,month,days,hours,minutes,seconds ago,

Comment: Ah! "ago" is the magic word. For that you do want a difference between now. now() - asked_date = time ago.

Use `strtotime()` to get the asked_date time, use `now()` to get the current time, subtract now from asked_date to get the difference between the time in seconds, then do basic math to figure out the different in different time units.

Comment: Or, more simply, `date_diff()` -> http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-diff.php Check the examples/comments

Answer (score 0):

You could try splitting this using preg_split.

Try something like

```
$output = preg_split( "/ (-| |:) /", $input );
```

That should give you an array, where the first element is the year, second is the month, and so on.