# PHP DateTime diff

Tags: php, datetime, diff, days

This may be a complete noob question but here goes:

I have the following code that compares two dates for absence management. Where I expect the answer to return as 2 (the difference between start and end date) I get 1.

```
$start_time = new DateTime("2015-01-01 00:00:00");
$end_time = new DateTime("2015-01-02 00:00:00");
$diff = $end_time->diff($start_time);
$d = $diff->days; // 1
```

I have also tried using just the dates (but I need the times as some absence type are done by hours not days)

Comment: The appropriate page from the [PHP Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php)

Comment: There is 1 day between 01-01 and 01-02. Why do you expect 2 as result?

Comment: Remove the `-`, and you have a simple subtraction problem. `20150102 - 20150101 = 1`.

Comment: Have you asked Google? http://bit.ly/192dcgw

Comment: I'm expecting 2 because 2015-01-01 is the first day of absence and 2015-01-02 is the last day of absence. I have man-flu which is why I have resorted to posting this noob question as my head can't work it out at the moment!!!

Comment: @user460510: DateTime doesn’t care about your _totally arbitrary_ additional meanings that you assign to those dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Difference is 1 because there is only one day difference between both days.
To convert the datetime into hours or minutes you should look to these links:

[Convert datetime into year, month, days, hours, minutes, seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18857507/convert-datetime-into-year-month-days-hours-minutes-seconds-in-php-show-onl)

[Difference between 2 time() values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18787790/difference-between-2-time-values/18787809#18787809)