# display hours and minutes after calculating difference between 2 unix times php

Tags: php

i have been having trouble displaying the hours and minutes after calculating the difference between 2 different unix timestamps. Lets say i have these 2 unix timestamps:

```
1) 1384327800
2) 1384300800
```

the difference is

```
27000
```

if i divide 27000/3600 i get

```
7.5
```

but what i want is to display

```
7:30
```

or

```
7 hours and 30 minutes
```

what is the best way to go about this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between 2 time() values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18787790/difference-between-2-time-values)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to calculate the difference between two dates using PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18863012/67332)

Comment: thank you for all the replies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All you need to do it a little calculation:

```
$diff = 27000;

$hour = floor($diff / 3600);
$min  = floor(($diff - $hour * 3600) / 60);
$sec = $diff - $hour * 3600 - $min * 60;

echo "$hour hours, $min minutes, $sec seconds";
```

Or try it with DateTime class:

```
$dt1 = new DateTime('@1384327800');
$dt2 = new DateTime('@1384300801');
$diff = $dt1->diff($dt2);
echo $diff->format('%h hours, %i minutes, %s seconds');
```

Comment: @user2835653: np, glad I can help.

Comment: Note that sometimes it'll incorrect pluralize time components.

Comment: [This example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18863012/67332) can be used to correctly pluralize time components; like this [demo](https://eval.in/67316).

Answer (score 3):

Algorithmic way (with no automatic calculation with any function/library) :

```
$diff_in_minutes = ($timestamp1 - $timestamp2) / 60;
$minutes = $diff_in_minutes % 60;
$hours = ($diff_in_minutes - $minutes) / 60;

$diff_string = $hours . ':' . $minutes;
```

Answer (score 2):

Look at [`DateTime()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) and [`DateInterval::format()`](http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php)

```
$dt1 = new DateTime('@1384327800');
$dt2 = new DateTime('@1384300800');
$diff = $dt1->diff($dt2);
echo $diff->format('%h hours and %i minutes');
```

This last little bit will remove unnecessary time periods from your string if so desired.

```
$elapsed = $diff->format('%y years, %m months, %a days, %h hours, %i minutes, %S seconds');
$elapsed = str_replace(array('0 years,', ' 0 months,', ' 0 days,',  ' 0 hours,', ' 0 minutes,'), '', $elapsed);
$elapsed = str_replace(array('1 years, ', ' 1 months, ', ' 1 days, ',  ' 1 hours, ', ' 1 minutes'), array('1 year, ', '1 month, ', ' 1 day, ', ' 1 hour, ', ' 1 minute'), $elapsed);
echo $elapsed;
```

Comment: This code is invalid. `%a` is used, where `%d` should be. If difference is `10 years`, you replace that with empty string (`0 years` => `''`). If difference is `11 years`, it is replaced with `11 year` (`1 years` => `1 year`).

Answer (score 1):

For full long formatting exactly as described:

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
$timestamp1 = new DateTime('@1384327800');
$timestamp2 = new DateTime('@1384300800');
$diff = $timestamp1->diff($timestamp2);
$timemap = array('y' => 'year',
                 'm' => 'month',
                 'd' => 'day',
                 'h' => 'hour',
                 'i' => 'minute',
                 's' => 'second');
$timefmt = array();

foreach ($timemap as $prop => $desc) {
    if ($diff->$prop > 0) {
        $timefmt[] = ($diff->$prop > 1) ? "{$diff->$prop} {$desc}s" : "{$diff->$prop} $desc";
    }
}

$diffstr = (count($timefmt) > 1)
    ? $diff->format(sprintf('%s and %s',
          implode(', ', array_slice($timefmt, 0, -1)), end($timefmt)))
    : end($timefmt);
var_dump($diffstr);
```

This gave me the following:

```
string(22) "7 hours and 30 minutes"
```